# ACPI Error On Dell Inspiron 3480 Ubuntu 20.04LTS

Tags: acpi

I contact you for technical assistance, I have a DELL INSPIRON 3480 notebook, Intel Core i5 ​​8265U, 16GB RAM, SSD NVME M.2 240GB, HDD 300GB, which I was using with UBUNTU 18.04LTS. When updating to UBUNTU 20.04 LTS, it began to present problems when starting the OS, after loading GRUB I get the following errors:

```
[ 0.197718] ACPI ERROR: NO POINTER BACK TO NAMESPACE NODE IN PACKAGE 00000000 b3a69038 (20200528/dsargs-301)
[ 0.208027] ACPI ERROR: NO POINTER BACK TO NAMESPACE NODE IN PACKAGE 00000000 b3a69038 (20200528/dsargs-301)
[ 0.209985] ACPI ERROR: NO POINTER BACK TO NAMESPACE NODE IN PACKAGE 00000000 b3a69038 (20200528/dsargs-301)
[ 0.211327] ACPI ERROR: NO POINTER BACK TO NAMESPACE NODE IN PACKAGE 00000000 b3a69038 (20200528/dsargs-301)
[ 0.212523] ACPI ERROR: NO POINTER BACK TO NAMESPACE NODE IN PACKAGE 00000000 b3a69038 (20200528/dsargs-301)
[ 0.213681] ACPI ERROR: NO POINTER BACK TO NAMESPACE NODE IN PACKAGE 00000000 b3a69038 (20200528/dsargs-301)
[ 0.215240] ACPI ERROR: NO POINTER BACK TO NAMESPACE NODE IN PACKAGE 00000000 b3a69038 (20200528/dsargs-301)
[ 0.216486] ACPI ERROR: NO POINTER BACK TO NAMESPACE NODE IN PACKAGE 00000000 b3a69038 (20200528/dsargs-301)
[ 0.218377] ACPI ERROR: NO POINTER BACK TO NAMESPACE NODE IN PACKAGE 00000000 b3a69038 (20200528/dsargs-301)
[ 0.219640] ACPI ERROR: NO POINTER BACK TO NAMESPACE NODE IN PACKAGE 00000000 b3a69038 (20200528/dsargs-301)
[ 1.537474] psmouse serio1: elantech: elantech_send_cmd query 0x02 failed.
[ 1.537542] psmouse serio1: elantech: failed to query capabilities.
/dev/nvmen1p1: recovering journal
```

This error prevented the operating system from starting. I managed to solve it by adding the following to the GRUB parameters: `libata.noacpi=1`, but with each update of KERNEL the problem appears again.

Please help solving this problem.